# How to extract multiple values from a line of particular fields using awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am having a file "file1.txt" which is having the data as follows:

> rahul 1994 Australia 40000
>   akash 2000 India     50000

Now i want to extract values of field 1 and field 4 in some variable.
I am doing it as follows:

```
while read line  
do  
  name=$(awk '{print $1}'<< "$line")  
  salary=$(awk '{print $4}'<< "$line")  
  echo $name $salary
done < file1.txt
```

So i want to ask that can i assign values to name and salary by using only one awk command?

Comment: If `awk '{print $1, $4}' file1.txt` isn't all you need then [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and provide the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: Or `cut -d " " -f 1,4 file1.txt` or `sed -E 's/ [^ ]+ [^ ]+//' file1.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better do this in plain [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) ;

```
while read name _ _ salary; do    
  echo "$name $salary"
done < file1.txt
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I need to store value also in variables 'name' and 'salary' for some other requirement. So can't i assign values to both variables using only one awk?

Comment: What ? I already store values in the named variables, what's wrong and what's the point using awk ?

Comment: @user12979043, the `read` command can assign separate words from the input line into separate variables, as Gilles demonstrates. This is exactly what you are asking for. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read